# migrate nonstandard layout svn to git without losing history

Tags: git, svn, migration

Suppose I have svn repo named XYZProject, it has one trunk which is my development base code and having 3 branches VF1, VF2 & VF3 and its layout is as shown below:

```
XYZProject 
   ..trunk
   ..VF1
      ..trunk_vf1
   ..VF2
      ..src
      ..doc
   ..VF3
      ..doc_vf3, 
      ..trunk_vf3 
      ..src_vf3
```

using git-svn tool and command is :

```
git svn clone -r623:HEAD http://svnURL/XYZProject --username barodia -T trunk -b VF1 -b VF2 -b VF3 --authors-file=authors.txt --no-minimize-url
```

it creates the branches of sub-folders present in VF1,VF2 and VF3 as like below:

```
$ git branch -a
*master
trunk
trunk_vf1
src
doc
doc_vf3
trunk_vf3
src_vf3
```

That means during svn clone it creates the path in my local as below:

```
origin/trunk
origin/trunk_vf1
origin/src
origin/doc
origin/doc_vf3
origin/trunk_vf3
origin/src_vf3
```

But I want the branches of VF1, VF2, VF3 like as below:

```
$ git branch -a
*master
trunk
VF1
VF2
VF3
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out the directory structures. Perhaps you could reformat your question and make it legible using `<pre>`?

Comment: @ThomasTimbul, Suppose I have a project named XYZProject and its layout is as below:

<br>
<pre>
    XYZProject,
    XYZProject/trunk,  
    YZProject/VF1,
    XYZProject/VF1/trunk,
    XYZProject/VF2,
    XYZProject/VF2/src,
    XYZProject/VF2/doc,
    XYZProject/VF3,
    XYZProject/VF3/doc,
    XYZProject/VF3/trunk,
    XYZProject/VF3/src
</pre>

<br>

using git-svn tool it create the branches of sub-folders present in VF1,VF2 and VF3 branches, But i want branch of VF1, VF2, VF3 and trunk as a branch.

Comment: Please edit the question - formatting doesn't show up in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but this may be an alternative for other non-standard layouts:
https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

The usage page shows a list of supported layouts styles.

**Edit:**
This might work for you:

```
svn2git http://svnURL/XYZProject --revision 623 --username abc --notrunk --notags --branches http://svnURL/XYZProject --authors authors.txt --branches --no-minimize-url
```

The idea being to not treat the root as trunk, but as the branches dir.
See the [svn2git Options Reference](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git#options-reference) and consider the addition of `-v` for verbose logging to aid debugging.

Comment: As per the above doc, it will create branches of all the sub-folder available under the branches folder.
Like.. 
proVF(branch path)
   .VF
   .VF2
trunk(trunk path)

svn2bit will create:
 $ git branch
   * master
     VF
     VF2

But I want it like this:
 $ git branch
   * master
     proVF

Can we create branches from that specified folder (proVF) instead of its sub-folders ?

Comment: This svn2git tool, what it does is, it creates a .git hidden folder in the project's root that contains all the information about the project.
It stores the branches in refs/remotes/origin/<creates branches  by the sub-folder names>, but i want it as refs/remotes/origin/<VF1,VF2,VF3>.
 => Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Have you actually tried running the command as updated above?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned it creates the branches of sub-folder!